# Premature end of script headers in python script bluehost

Tags: python, ajax, http-headers, cgi, bluehost

I'm hosting a website off of Bluehost and I'm trying to execute a python script on a button click using AJAX. However every time I click the button the server responds with a 500 error to the python script. More specifically this is the error:

> [Sun Nov 30 17:49:26 2014] [error] [client 174.61.70.33] Premature end
>   of script headers: Steap.py, referer: http://steap.co/

This is the AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#steambutton").click(function() {
                DisplayLoadingDiv();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://steap.co/cgi-bin/Steap.py",
                    data: {steamid: "<?php echo $steamprofile['steamid']?>"},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#steamdiv").html(response);  
                        $("#phisherbutton").show()
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        $("#steamdiv").html("An error occured. Please try again.");
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

Basically the div is showing `"An error occured. Please try again."` after 0.01 secs of execution, and the console shows that the server responded with a 500 error when trying to load the python script resource.

**Steap.py**:

http://pastebin.com/F9THyt3u

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: So... `steap.co` is your server, right? Do you see any error in that server logs?

Comment: steap.co is the website, not the server. And this is the error in the server logs: `[Sun Nov 30 17:49:26 2014] [error] [client 174.61.70.33] Premature end of script headers: Steap.py, referer: http://steap.co/`

Comment: Potato, poteito... **:-D** So where does that `Steap.py` run exactly? I mean... I don't see how everything is connected here... Your're sending a `POST` to `steap.co` which runs... who knows where... And that is giving you an HTTP 500... Where does `Steap.py` come into play here.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it...

Comment: `Steap.py` is in a cgi-bin folder of my site directory. I just make a post request to the `Steap.py` resource, which is in that cgi-bin folder.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a raw HTTP response using `print`. That's ok (a lot of work, but doable) but it looks like it's malformed. I'm trying to see exactly how the headers, body... and stuff are formed in plain text, but it seems to me (to me, which I'm guessing here) that you are missing "chunks" to have a well formed HTTP response (I'll keep searching, though) In the meantime, have you considering using a built-in server that handles that for you? Dunno... Django or Tornado? (mainly so you have to write less stuff)

Comment: No I have not considered doing that. But I have used a local Apache webserver for testing the website on localhost and everything worked fine. Could there be a problem with headers?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is :-) Almost there (writing an answer now)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the issue is, that you're not properly forming an HTTP response in `Steap.py`. Particularly important is the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n` part (the *[Status Line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)*)

I've set up in my computer a raw TCP socket implementation (using [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html)) and it correctly renders a page in my web browser by doing the following:

```
    import datetime
    body=("<html><title>Hello</title>"
          "<body>"
          "<div id=\"div-name\">"
          "%s"
          "</br></br>"
          "</div>"
          "</body>"
          "</html>" % foo(bar))

    reply=("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
           "Date: %s\n"
           "Content-Type: text/html\n"
           "Content-Length: %s\n"
           "Connection: close\n"
           "\n"
           "%s" 
           % (datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(' '),
              len(body),
              body)
    )
    print reply
```

This looks nicely displayed in Chrome:

[image]

Needless to say, but this is my `foo(bar)` function:

```
def foo(bar):
    return "Test test"
```

All this said, I'd really, really study how to install a pre-made server (such as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)) in your *Bluehost* "area" (or however you wanna call it). I lean towards Tornado (its usage is very basic, but it'll help a lot so you don't have to "manually" write headers and bodies by yourself)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I changed my code to this: http://pastebin.com/DDVuUWT7

Comment: Since it seems that what you `print` is the response sent to your browser, I'd remove (or comment) the line `print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"` (line 21). That could be interpreted by your browser as an "orphan" header?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you might wanna edit your question and add a bit more of the contents of `Steap.py`?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I'll edit my question to show the full contents of `Steap.py`

Comment: I can't tell for sure if what I'm about to say is the source of your error, but you're adding a `+` to concatenate the different parts of `body` and `reply`. That's gonna give you an error when combined with `%s` (each `"" + ""` will create 2 different strings, so `"%s" + "%s" % ('whatever', 'whatever')` will throw you an exception (will try to put the two `whatevers` into the last `"%s"` string, and none in the first `"%s"` )

Comment: Also, don't try to call your `getFriendList(steeam)` and `grabPhisherIDs()` when building the `body` just yet. If they throw an error, you'll have difficulties finding where. Just try to get a really, really simple HTTP response rendering in your browser. Once you have that, start adding the "real" functionalities.

Comment: After some research (http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?19972-Can-I-install-tornado-in-bluehost), it seems that I can't use Tornado, and I have to utilize Apache instead, which is perfectly fine, because the python code works because I used xampp, apache and a localhost website to run the code and it worked perfectly fine. So now how do I configure Apache to run my python code correctly, more importantly the headers?

Comment: On a different note... are you allowing people to upload PHP code into your server that you then happily run? ....